# Flip Language content in Salesforce Email Template based on contact language preference

Tags: visualforce, email-template, email2case, case-auto-response

We have a custom field on Contact > Language Preference.
Currently it holds English and French values.

We want to create a auto-response template that will show both English and French to the contact when say a Case is created.

> **Now the requirement is to show English content at top and French content at bottom if contact's language preference is English and show French content at top and English content at bottom if contact's language preference is French.**

I could not find any other question on the same here in forum.

Please advise on if we can achieve that and how?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use a VF template to dynamically generate content based on user language or you can use two different templates for each user language and switch them based on user's language.

Comment: it should be based on contact's language and select which content to put at top automatically at run time while sending auto-emails..